# Need input on SQL Pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

Need input on sql query . I have seen examples but all of them use aggregate functions, hence posting the question..

MY TABLE Looks like

```
Values          ID      Name
59.781437   7053    263
16.478765   7053    264
38.950151   7054    263
72.01498    7054    264
```

I want to produce data as below ( with or without pivot )

```
ID   263       264
7053 59.781437 16.478765
7054 38.950151 72.01498
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
select * from
(
select * from MyTable
) as src
pivot(
sum([values])
for Name in ([263], [264])
) as pvt
```

When Name column can have unspecified number of values, use this instead -

```
create table ##tmp(
name varchar(50) null
)
insert into ##tmp
select distinct name from mytable

DECLARE @result nvarchar(max)
SET @result = ''

SELECT @result = @result + '[' + cast([name] as varchar(50)) + N'],'
FROM [##tmp]

SET @result = LEFT(@result, LEN(@result) - 1)

--PRINT @result 

declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
SET @sql = 
'select * from' + 
'(
select * from MyTable
) as src
pivot(
sum([values])
for Name in (' + @result + ')' +
+ ') as pvt'

exec (@sql)

drop table ##tmp
```

The key points - We used our simple query to make the above query. Then, we used dynamic sql to execute our above query.

Comment: Not quiet right, it is producing the result as below . The Id gets repeated across rows, but I want to produce only one row per each ID 
This produces the following output

ID 263              264
7053    59.781437        NULL
7053    NULL             16.478765
7054    38.950151 NULL
7054    NULL  72.01498

Comment: @user476566 - Well, that is because Name has more than 2 values, i.e 263, 264. Read a bit about pivot.

Comment: @user476566 - My new answer will work. Please select it as an answer once you are sure.

Comment: Print @sql returns empty, trying to debug .

Comment: MY sql output only shows 11 rows effected , but does not show the formatted output ( note I commented the drop table and was hoping the exec (@sql) will show result set.

Comment: @user476566 - This code worked on my system with your sample data. I don't know why the results are different on your side. Try to understand my query and edit it to get the output you want. I can't do your work for you.

Comment: the issue was in my actual dataset , the names column contained NULL Values. it works now.

Comment: @user476566 - You used select distinct, where name is not null ? Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I used select distinct, where name is not null